# Fingerprinting externally generated static content (ASP.NET + browserify)

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, node.js, bundling-and-minification

Nodejs [`browserify`](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#introduction) is terrific when building modular js apps. If `gulp` is part of the setup as well, the workflow [is further enhanced](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/recipes) to manage and resolve dependencies, *properly* bundle, uglify with sourcemaps, auto-polyfill, jshint, test... This is pretty handy for css as well with pre-processing, auto-prefixing, linting, embedding resources and generating documentation.

TL;DR: with npm/bower you get access to an extensive ecosystem of front-end libraries, making nodejs perfect for building (not necessarily serving!) client-side code. In fact, using it for client-side code is so awesome that `npm`, `bower` and `grunt`/`gulp` will be supported out of the box in VS 2015. In the meantime, we have set up a gulp task that runs pre-build and writes dist js/css (bundling output).

**What's a good way to reference external static content with fingerprinted urls?** In the long run we would ideally be able to separate client-side content icompletely so it could be independently built and deployed to CDN without having to build the rest of the application as well.

Comment: what's a "fingerprinted url"?

Comment: @dandavis: it's a technique to invalidate stale content when [aggressively caching](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching) assets. This behaviour (cache busting) is typically done referencing file version or hash "fingerprint" in the URL i.e. `app.js?v=123`; whenever an update is released the file is served from a different URL.

Comment: as seen from the client, are all the urls hard-coded into the html as attribs like src and href?

Comment: @dandavis: not sure I follow; the fingerprinted url is rendered into the page if that's what you're asking

Comment: well, every place where that url shows up is a place that will need updating upon rebuild. if you use some sort of a client-side resource loader, you can leave one file un-perma-baked, and it contains all the urls of your resources. that way, you can update that single file and update all your users at once, or certain groups, whatever. as it stands, you basically have to update your links when you update resources, there's no easy way around that if you want point to unexpireable urls in many places. a JS based loader can help, but it's still not that great for CSS...

Comment: To summerize what I understood: 1. your are using browserify and gulp ant its cool. 2. you cannot use it in VS now (so what?) 3. your actual question: there is some problem with referencing resources and building application. So please show us: how you reference the resources, how you build the application and what is not working there. Is your question strictly connected with a build process of `asp.net` application or are you asking about bundling resources in general situation?

Answer (score 1):

**Problems with CSS**

Since CSS references relative urls for images which might change as well, and you will need to compute lot of hash calculation before starting your app which will slow down signature url generation. Turns out that writing code to track last modified date does not work with CSS image urls. So if any of image referred inside css changes, css must be changed as well.

**Problems with Individual File Versioning like jquery-1.11.1.js**

First it breaks source code versioning, Git or any version control will identify app-script-1.11.js and app-script-1.12.js as two different files, it will be difficult to maintain history.

For jquery, it will work as they are building library and most often you will not change it while including resources on your page, but while building application, we will have many JavaScript files and changing version will require changing each page, however, single include file might do it, but consider lots of css and lots of images.

**Cached Last Update date as URL Prefix**

So we had to come up with versioning of static content like `/cached/lastupdate/`, this is nothing but just a url prefix for static asset. `lastupdate` is nothing but last updated date-time of the requested file. There is also a watcher which refreshes cache key if file is modified during the scope of application.

Well one of the easiest approach is to use a version key in the URL.

Define version in app settings as follow

```
 <appSettings>
     <add key="CDNHost" value="cdn1111.cloudfront.net"/>
 </appSettings>

 // Route configuration

 // set CDN if you have
 string cdnHost = WebConfigrationManager.AppSettings["CDNHost"];
 if(!string.IsEmpty(cdnHost)){
     CachedRoute.CDNHost = cdnHost;
 }

 // get assembly build information
 string version = typeof(RouteConfig).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();

 CachedRoute.CORSOrigins = "*";
 CachedRoute.Register(routes, TimeSpam.FromDays(30), version);
```

Now on each page, reference your static content as,

```
 <script src="@CachedRoute.CachedUrl("/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js")"></script>
```

While rendering, your page will be rendered as (without CDN)

```
 <script src="/cached/2015-12-12-10-10-10-1111/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

With CDN as

```
 <script 
      src="//cdn111.cloudfront.net/cached/2015-12-12-10-10-10-1111/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js">
 </script>
```

Putting version in URL path instead of query string makes CDN perform better as query strings can be ignored in CDN configuration (which is usually the default case).

CachedRoute Class from
https://github.com/neurospeech/atoms-mvc.net/blob/master/src/Mvc/CachedRoute.cs

```
public class CachedRoute : HttpTaskAsyncHandler, IRouteHandler
{

    private CachedRoute()
    {
        // only one per app..

    }

    private string Prefix { get; set; }

    public static string Version { get; private set; }

    private TimeSpan MaxAge { get; set; }

    public static string CORSOrigins { get; set; }
    //private static CachedRoute Instance;

    public static void Register(
        RouteCollection routes,
        TimeSpan? maxAge = null,
        string version = null)
    {
        CachedRoute sc = new CachedRoute();
        sc.MaxAge = maxAge == null ? TimeSpan.FromDays(30) : maxAge.Value;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(version))
        {
            version = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Static-Content-Version"];
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(version))
            {
                version = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
            }
        }

        Version = version;

        var route = new Route("cached/{version}/{*name}", sc);
        route.Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary();
        route.Defaults["version"] = "1";
        routes.Add(route);
    }

    public override bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static string CDNHost { get; set; }

    public override bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class CachedFileInfo
    {

        public string Version { get; set; }

        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        public CachedFileInfo(string path)
        {
            path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);

            FilePath = path;

            //Watch();

            Update(null, null);
        }

        private void Watch()
        {
            System.IO.FileSystemWatcher fs = new FileSystemWatcher(FilePath);
            fs.Changed += Update;
            fs.Deleted += Update;
            fs.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.FileName;
        }

        private void Update(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(FilePath);
            if (f.Exists)
            {
                Version = f.LastWriteTimeUtc.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss-FFFF");
            }
            else
            {
                Version = "null";
            }
        }


    }

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, CachedFileInfo> CacheItems = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CachedFileInfo>();

    public static HtmlString CachedUrl(string p)
    {
        //if (!Enabled)
        //    return new HtmlString(p);
        if (!p.StartsWith("/"))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Please provide full path starting with /");

        string v = Version;

        var cv = CacheItems.GetOrAdd(p, k => new CachedFileInfo(k));
        v = cv.Version;

        if (CDNHost != null)
        {
            return new HtmlString("//" + CDNHost + "/cached/" + v + p);
        }
        return new HtmlString("/cached/" + v + p);
    }

    public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var Response = context.Response;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(MaxAge);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.Add(MaxAge));

        if (CORSOrigins != null)
        {
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", CORSOrigins);
        }


        string FilePath = context.Items["FilePath"] as string;

        var file = new FileInfo(context.Server.MapPath("/" + FilePath));
        if (!file.Exists)
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(file.FullName);
        }

        Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(file.FullName);

        using (var fs = file.OpenRead())
        {
            await fs.CopyToAsync(Response.OutputStream);
        }
    }

    IHttpHandler IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        //FilePath = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("name");
        requestContext.HttpContext.Items["FilePath"] = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("name");
        return (IHttpHandler)this;
    }
}
```

**Using File Modification Time instead of Version**

```
    public static HtmlString CachedUrl(string p)
    {
        if (!p.StartsWith("/"))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Please provide full path starting with /");
        var ft = (new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath(p)).LastModified;
        return new HtmlString(cdnPrefix + "/cached/" + ft.Ticks + p);
    }
```

This retains version based on last modification, but this increases call to `System.IO.FileInfo` on every request, however you can create another dictionary to cache this information and watch for changes, but it is lot of work.

Comment: Detailed implementation, thanks. It is preferred to version individual static assets rather than the entire set though, e.g. a release changes a.js but not b.js or c.js yet all three get their script tags rendered with a new src.

Comment: Individual versions are often difficult while making many changes especially in agile method, however common resources like jquery-1.11.1.min.js can be loaded directly from google CDN and this CachedRoute should only be used for our own resource files only. I agree it is little overhead with every release, but it simply isolates all dependent resources in individual release.

Comment: Other alternative is to use File Modified Time and use it instead of version, this will force URL to embed file modified time, but this will also force checks to File Modified time, (which is system file call), every time a request is made to IIS. It turns out that this call is unnecessary call for every request and it is better to leave global version.

Answer (score -1):

Just version it after each release and update the url:

[https://cdn.contoso.com/libs/module/**2.2**/module.js](http://google.com/)

Comment: Versioning after each release invalidates cache for every resource even if it wasn't modified.