# Get MVC Bundle Querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, query-string, bundling-and-minification

Is it possible to detect a bundle querystring in ASP.NET MVC?

For example if I have the following bundle request:

> /css/bundles/mybundle.css?v=4Z9jKRKGzlz-D5dJi5VZtpy4QJep62o6A-xNjSBmKwU1

Is it possible to extract the `v` querystring?:

> 4Z9jKRKGzlz-D5dJi5VZtpy4QJep62o6A-xNjSBmKwU1

---

I've tried doing this in a bundle transform, but with no luck. I found that even with `UseServerCache` set to `false` the transform code didn't always run.

Comment: Curious as to why you would want it?

Comment: @DavidG I have a server farm and want to check the current server has the correct files so that a newer cache buster doesn't cache old content. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535879/prevent-bundle-from-responding-if-cache-buster-doesnt-match-content

Comment: You could use `Styles.Render("~/blah.css")` to get the `<link...` as a string, then extract the value from there.

Comment: @DavidG That will get what that server produces. There might be a different version in cache from a newer/older version of the application from another server in the farm. I plan to compare the value you mention against the one in the request to ensure they match :)

Comment: this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You believe Y will solve some problem X, but you haven't described X.  What problem (X) is getting the value `v` going to solve(Y)?

Comment: @ErikPhilips This is the problem I'm trying to solve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535879/prevent-bundle-from-responding-if-cache-buster-doesnt-match-content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while since I've worked with the ASP Bundler (I remember it being terrible), and these notes are from my memory. Please verify that it's still valid.
Hopefully this will provide a starting point for your search.

To tackle this problem you'll want to explore around in `System.Web.Optimization namespace`.

Of most importance is the `System.Web.Optimization.BundleResponse` class, which has a method named `GetContentHashCode()` which is exactly what you want. Unfortunately, MVC Bundler has a bad architecture and I'm willing to bet that this is still an internal method. This means you won't be able to call it from your code.

---

**Update**

Thanks for the verification. So it looks like you have a few ways of accomplishing your goal:

1. Compute the hash your self using the same algorithm as ASP Bundler
2. Use reflection to call into the internal method of the Bundler
3. Get the URL from bundler (there is a public method for this I believe) and extract the query string, then extract the hash from that (using any string extraction methods)
4. Get angry at Microsoft for bad design

Lets go with #2 (Be careful, since its marked as internal and not part of the public API, a rename of the method by the Bundler team will break things)

```
//This is the url passed to bundle definition in BundleConfig.cs
string bundlePath = "~/bundles/jquery";
//Need the context to generate response
var bundleContext = new BundleContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), BundleTable.Bundles, bundlePath);

//Bundle class has the method we need to get a BundleResponse
Bundle bundle = BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor(bundlePath);
var bundleResponse = bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(bundleContext);

//BundleResponse has the method we need to call, but its marked as
//internal and therefor is not available for public consumption.
//To bypass this, reflect on it and manually invoke the method
var bundleReflection = bundleResponse.GetType();

var method = bundleReflection.GetMethod("GetContentHashCode", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

//contentHash is whats appended to your url (url?###-###...)
var contentHash = method.Invoke(bundleResponse, null);
```

The `bundlePath` variable is the same name that you gave to the bundle (from `BundleConfig.cs`)

Hope this helps! Good Luck!

Edit: Forgot to say that it would be a good idea to add a test around this. The test would check for the existence of the `GetHashCode` function. This way, in the future, should the internals of the Bundler change the test will fail and you'll know where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks Frison, I think you're correct about the `GetContentHashCode()` being private, I came across this earlier - http://forums.asp.net/t/1809372.aspx?System+Web+Optimization+Bundle+GetContentHashCode+private+why+

Comment: Please let me know if you find out another way when you get chance!